# If a real-valued sequence of functions is uniformly bounded , then it is pointwise bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, self-learning

Show that if $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly bounded real-valued sequence, then it is pointwise bounded.

It seems quite obvious that $\mid f_n (x)\mid \leq M, \forall n,x$ means that for every $x, \mid f_n(x)\mid \leq M, \forall n$. How can I formally prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the difference.

Comment: You don’t really have to do anything at all, to be honest. If you want to really nitpick your way through it and be remarkably thorough (I can’t imagine why else this question would exist) I would basically just write out the definitions formally, consider the first forall statement in the pointwise definition to “introduce” such an element, and then “apply” that same element back into the forall in the uniform definition (doing that where appropriate). It’s just the sort of detail human mathematicians never bother with at all unless writing it up in a verification language.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation

Comment: @JackCrawford You are right. It was given to me as a homework exercise. But as I highlighted above, it is obvious (a particular case of uniformly boundeness).

Comment: The reason for the exercise might just be to call your attention to the fact that the statement is true, even though the proof is trivial.  This is relevant, for instance, when trying to use the Arzela-Ascoli theorem: one of the hypotheses is pointwise boundedness, but in many applications you may actually have uniform boundedness, and it's helpful to be able to recognize immediately that this is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D$ be the domain of your functions. You are assuming that there is a number $M>0$ such that$$(\forall x\in D)(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\bigl\lvert f_n(x)\bigr\rvert\leqslant M.\tag1$$Now, take $x\in D$. It follows from $(1)$ that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\bigl\lvert f_n(x)\bigr\rvert\leqslant M.$$